# Why do we need to extend JFrame in a swing application?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Why do we need to extend the `JFrame` class when building a Swing application. As far as I know `extends` is used for inheriting the base class. None of the functions of the `JFrame` class are used in the following program but still it is extended. I know I am missing out on some information. Is it like some of the functions of JFrame class are running in the background.

1) Code

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class tuna extends JFrame{

   private JTextField item1;
   private JTextField item2;
   private JTextField item3;
   private JPasswordField passwordField;
   Container contentPane ;
   public tuna(){
      super("The title");

      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      item1 = new JTextField(10);
      contentPane.add(item1);

      item2 = new JTextField("enter text here");
      add(item2);

      item3 = new JTextField("uneditable", 20);
      item3.setEditable(false);
      add(item3);

      passwordField = new JPasswordField("mypass");
      add(passwordField);

      thehandler handler = new thehandler();

      item1.addActionListener(handler);
      item2.addActionListener(handler);
      item3.addActionListener(handler);
      passwordField.addActionListener(handler);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      tuna aye = new tuna();
   }

   private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
         String string = "";

         if(event.getSource()==item1)
            string=String.format("field 1: %s",event.getActionCommand());
         else if (event.getSource()==item2)
            string=String.format("field 2: %s",event.getActionCommand());
         else if (event.getSource()==item3)
            string=String.format("field 3: %s",event.getActionCommand());
         else if (event.getSource()==passwordField)
            string=String.format("password field is: %", event.getActionCommand());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The premise of this question is false. You don't have to extend a JFrame in order to use it.

Comment: actually, you should _not_ extend a JFrame (nor any other class except when you really enhance functionality, that is implement something that can't be achieved by using/configuring that class) - most tutorials and Netbeans are giving bad examples :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to extend JFrame and in fact many of us who do a lot of Swing programming make it a point *not* to extend this class. Myself, I try to extend classes where I plan on altering the innate behavior of the class -- i.e., override one of the non-static methods of the class. Since I rarely have to do this for a JFrame, I'll rarely want to extend it.

Another reason to avoid extending it: what if you later want to display the GUI you've just created in a JDialog or a JOptionPane or in another container as part of a complex GUI? If your class extends JFrame this will be hard to do. Myself, I try to gear my GUI classes towards creating JPanels so that this is much easier to do.

A silly example based on your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

// this guy extends *nothing*
public class TunaExample {
   private static final int COLS = 10;
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); // this is what I'll add to contentPane
   private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField field2 = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(COLS);
   private JComponent[] allComponents = { new JLabel("Field 1:"), field1,
         new JLabel("Field 2:"), field2, new JLabel("Password:"), passwordField };

   public TunaExample() {
      field2.setEditable(false);
      field2.setFocusable(false);
      field1.setText("Field 1");
      field2.setText("Uneditable");

      for (JComponent comp : allComponents) {
         mainPanel.add(comp);
      }
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TunaExample tunaExample = new TunaExample();

      // creating my JFrame only when I need it and where I need it
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tuna Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(tunaExample.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to note in your code is this:

```
super("The title");
```

This actually calls the `JFrame` constructor, and passed it `"The title"` as a title String. This is an explicit example of using the `Jframe` functionality in your code. This will build the window that appears for you.

Using methods like `add` are all inherited from the `JFrame` class. These add `Components` to the JFrame object.

**Why Inheritance?**

Well, simply, your class IS a JFrame, with a little more. When you have a `Is A` operation, you use inheritance. The other advantage of this method is that your class can be referred to as a JFrame. That is:

```
JFrame tuna = new tuna();
// Note: All classes are meant to start with a capital letter.
```

**Another viewpoint**

It's important to note that you don't strictly HAVE TO inherit from a JFrame class. You can use `Composition`. In this instance you'd have something like:

```
 public class Tuna {
      private JFrame parentWindow;
      // Rest of class.
 }
```

As mentioned above, the convention is to follow the `Is A` and `Has A` approach. If class `A` Is an example of class `B`, we tend to use inheritance. If class `A` has an instance of class `B`, then you use composition, although in most cases, inheritance is interchangeable  with Composition.

**Another another Viewpoint**

As mentioned in the comments, you should always look for an existing API that offers this kind of functionality, before attempting to implement it yourself.

Comment: I have one more question. When I am writing `JFrame tuna = new tuna();` am I creating object of JFrame class or am I referring the `tuna` class as a JFrame

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar: you are doing both. You are creating a tuna object (which should be named "Tuna" since it's a class) but since Tuna extends JFrame, it also *is a* JFrame. It is being held by a JFrame *variable* though and so the variable will not be able to reference any new methods that aren't already part of JFrame. 1+ to Chris's decent answer by the way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Learn something new every day!

Comment: a rule of thumb is: never extend if you can reach the same by _using_ existing api. Consequently, most of the later part of your answer is .. suboptimal :-) And _inheritance is interchangeable with Composition_ is simply wrong

Comment: @kleopatra In most cases, you can achieve the same functionality with Composition as you can with inheritance. I believe that's a perfectly sound statement. OP's question was about *why* we inherit from a superclass in the context of a JFrame. I feel that I have explained that quite well. I didn't think about API's, and I'll edit that in now.

Comment: repeating a statement that's incorrect doesn't make it correct ;-)

Comment: Being condescending doesn't help either. Can you explain why it's an incorrect statement?

Comment: sure - as can (better than me) any serious textbook on OO basics. No condescending intended, btw.

Comment: Agreed, but could you just quickly summarize it for me? If it's on here, any other readers will see this and I can ammend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To use `JFrame` in your application You can extend it as you did it in your  code or make an `object`  as

```
JFrame frame= new JFrame();
```

and then you can do it

```
frame.setTitle("Title");
frame.setLayout(layout);
```

do it in either way as you  are easy but to use JFrame in Application and to access its methods etc you have to use one of these methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a standalone application, you can either extend JPanel or JFrame or create their instance in your class implementation.

As a rule, a standalone application with a Swing-based GUI has at least one containment hierarchy with a JFrame as its root. For example, if an application has one main window and two dialogs, then the application has three containment hierarchies, and thus three top-level containers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html