# class Gui_Started is public, should be declared in a file named Gui_Started.java public class Gui_Started extends JFrame{

Tags: java, user-interface

i try to make project with notepad and debug it with cmd and I got an error for `class Gui_Started is public, should be declared in a file named Gui_Started.java public class Gui_Started extends JFrame{`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gui_Started extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gui_Started gui = new Gui_Started();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(500,500);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("Gui Pertama");

    }
}
```

Comment: So separate this code into another java file named, Gui_Started.java

Comment: a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: I can see this is swing not javafx

Comment: watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVldNE9UVPs

Comment: If you do not override methods in `JFrame`, you do not need to `extends JFrame`, simply create composition(`JFrame frame = new JFrame("title")`. read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867148/why-do-we-need-to-extend-jframe-in-a-swing-application

Comment: watch this: youtube.com/watch?v=CVldNE9UVPs
thank you, it works now

Comment: yes i do not need to extends, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java)