# Transform my Java Swing program to an MVC program?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, view, model

I was given the task to come up with a small game in Swing and implement it as an MVC (Model View Control) program. I'm new to MVC. So far I've finished the whole program in 1 Java file (View), what code do I need to change and insert in the Model file, in order for it to become MVC?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MemoryGameView extends JFrame {

private JPanel gamePanel, settingsPanel, scorePanel;

private JButton[] button = new JButton[16];
private JButton start;
private JPanel buttonPanel, buttonPanel2;


private JPanel difficultyPanel, difficultyPanel2;
private JLabel difficultyLabel;
private ButtonGroup difficultyButtonGroup;
private JRadioButton[] difficultyButton = new JRadioButton[4];
private int difficulty = 0;

private JComboBox guiColorChanger;
private String[] guiColor = new String[2];
private JPanel guiColorChangerPanel;
private JLabel guiColorChangerLabel;

private JPanel currentScorePanel, currentScorePanel2, highScorePanel, highScorePanel2;
private JLabel currentScoreLabel, currentScoreLabel2, highScoreLabel, highScoreLabel2;
private int currentScore;
private int highScore = 0;

private int[] arrayAuto;
private int[] arrayUser;
private int counter;

private Timer timer;

private Color babyBlue = new Color(137, 156, 240);
private Color brightRed = new Color(255, 69, 0);
private Color limeGreen = new Color(50, 205, 50);
private Color whiteBlue = new Color(240, 240, 255);
private Color blackBlue = new Color(0, 0, 15);

public MemoryGameView() {
    super();
    init();
}

public void init() {
    setTitle("Memory Game - by Marc");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1200, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    settingsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    scorePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    settingsPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    add(settingsPanel);
    add(gamePanel);
    add(scorePanel);

    //GAME PANEL (CENTER) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //GAME GRID PANEL:

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 4, 4));
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        button[x] = new JButton();
        button[x].setBackground(babyBlue);
        button[x].setEnabled(false);
        button[x].addActionListener(new AttemptMemoryGame());
        button[x].setActionCommand(x + "");
        buttonPanel.add(button[x]);
    }

    buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    buttonPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(312, 312));
    buttonPanel2.add(buttonPanel);
    GridBagConstraints buttonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    buttonGBC.gridy = 0;
    buttonGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
    gamePanel.add(buttonPanel2, buttonGBC);

    //START BUTTON:

    start = new JButton("START");
    start.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
    GridBagConstraints startGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    startGBC.gridy = 1;
    startGBC.insets.top = 20;
    startGBC.insets.bottom = 20;
    gamePanel.add(start, startGBC);

    start.addActionListener(new CreateMemoryGame());
    timer = new Timer(750, new TimerListener());

    //SETTINGS PANEL (LEFT) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //GUI COLOR PANEL:

    guiColor[0] = "Light";
    guiColor[1] = "Dark";

    guiColorChangerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    settingsPanel.add(guiColorChangerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    guiColorChanger = new JComboBox(guiColor);
    guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    guiColorChanger.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    GridBagConstraints guiColorChangerGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    guiColorChangerGBC.gridy = 1;
    guiColorChangerGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 0, 50);
    guiColorChangerGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    guiColorChangerPanel.add(guiColorChanger, guiColorChangerGBC);

    guiColorChangerLabel = new JLabel("GUI Color Mode:");
    GridBagConstraints guiColorChangerLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    guiColorChangerLabelGBC.gridy = 0;
    guiColorChangerLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(30, 20, 5, 0);
    guiColorChangerLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    guiColorChangerPanel.add(guiColorChangerLabel, guiColorChangerLabelGBC);

    guiColorChanger.addActionListener(new ChangeColorsGUI());
    guiColorChanger.setFocusable(false);
    
    //GAME DIFFICULTY PANEL:
    
    difficultyPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    difficultyPanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    settingsPanel.add(difficultyPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    difficultyLabel = new JLabel("Difficulty:");
    GridBagConstraints difficultyLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    difficultyLabelGBC.gridy = 0;
    difficultyLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(30, 0, 5, 50);
    difficultyLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    difficultyPanel2.add(difficultyLabel, difficultyLabelGBC);

    difficultyPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    GridBagConstraints difficultyPanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    difficultyPanelGBC.gridy = 1;
    difficultyPanelGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 75, 100);
    difficultyPanel2.add(difficultyPanel, difficultyPanelGBC);

    GridBagConstraints difficultyGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    difficultyGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    difficultyGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    difficultyButton[0] = new JRadioButton("Easy [3]");
    difficultyButton[1] = new JRadioButton("Normal [5]");
    difficultyButton[2] = new JRadioButton("Hard [7]");
    difficultyButton[3] = new JRadioButton("Impossible [9]");

    difficultyButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        difficultyButton[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        difficultyButton[x].setActionCommand(x + "");
        difficultyGBC.gridy = x;
        difficultyPanel.add(difficultyButton[x], difficultyGBC);
        difficultyButtonGroup.add(difficultyButton[x]);
        difficultyButton[x].addActionListener(new SelectDifficulty());
    }
    
    //SCORE PANEL (RIGHT) --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    //CURRENT SCORE:

    currentScorePanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    currentScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    scorePanel.add(currentScorePanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    currentScoreLabel2 = new JLabel("Score:        ");
    GridBagConstraints currentScoreLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    currentScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 0;
    currentScoreLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    currentScoreLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    currentScorePanel2.add(currentScoreLabel2, currentScoreLabelGBC);

    currentScorePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    currentScorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    GridBagConstraints currentScorePanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    currentScorePanelGBC.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 100, 100);
    currentScorePanelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    currentScorePanel2.add(currentScorePanel, currentScorePanelGBC);

    currentScoreLabel = new JLabel("        ");
    currentScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 1;
    currentScorePanel.add(currentScoreLabel, currentScoreLabelGBC);

    
    //HIGHSCORE:

    highScorePanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    highScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
    scorePanel.add(highScorePanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    highScoreLabel2 = new JLabel("Highscore: ");
    GridBagConstraints highScoreLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    highScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 0;
    highScoreLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    highScoreLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    highScorePanel2.add(highScoreLabel2, highScoreLabelGBC);

    highScorePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    highScorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    GridBagConstraints highScorePanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    highScorePanelGBC.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 100, 100);
    highScorePanelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    highScorePanel2.add(highScorePanel, highScorePanelGBC);

    highScoreLabel = new JLabel("        ");
    highScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 1;
    highScorePanel.add(highScoreLabel, highScoreLabelGBC);
    
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public class CreateMemoryGame implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (difficulty != 0) {
            counter = 0;
            for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                rb.setEnabled(false);
            }
            for (JButton b: button) {
                b.setBackground(babyBlue);
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
            start.setEnabled(false);
            arrayAuto = new int[difficulty];
            arrayAuto[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
            for (int x = 1; x < difficulty; x++) {
                arrayAuto[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
                while (arrayAuto[x] == arrayAuto[x - 1]) {
                    arrayAuto[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
                }
            }
            arrayUser = Arrays.copyOf(arrayAuto, arrayAuto.length);
            button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(limeGreen);
            timer.start();
        } else {
            Object[] options = {"OK"};
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please select a Difficulty.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    options,
                    options[0]);
        }
    }
}

public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(babyBlue);
        arrayAuto = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayAuto, 1, arrayAuto.length);
        if (arrayAuto.length == 0) {
            timer.stop();
            for (JButton b: button) {
                b.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(limeGreen);
        }
    }
}

public class AttemptMemoryGame implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand()) == arrayUser[counter]) {
            if (counter != 0) {
                button[arrayUser[counter - 1]].setBackground(babyBlue);
            }
            button[arrayUser[counter]].setBackground(limeGreen);
            counter++;
            currentScore += difficulty;
            currentScoreLabel.setText("  " + currentScore + "  ");
        } else {
            if (currentScore > highScore) {
                highScore = currentScore;
                highScoreLabel.setText("  " + highScore + "  ");
            }
            currentScore = 0;
            currentScoreLabel.setText("        ");
            for (int x = 0; x < difficulty; x++) {
                button[arrayUser[x]].setBackground(brightRed);
            }
            start.setEnabled(true);
            for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                rb.setEnabled(true);
            }
            for (JButton b: button) {
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        if (counter == arrayUser.length) {
            start.setEnabled(true);
            for (int x = 0; x < counter - 1; x++) {
                button[arrayUser[x]].setBackground(limeGreen);
            }
            for (JButton b: button) {
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
            for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                rb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SelectDifficulty implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(0 + "")) {
            difficulty = 3;
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(2 + "")) {
            difficulty = 7;
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(3 + "")) {
            difficulty = 9;
        } else {
            difficulty = 5;
        }
    }
}

public class ChangeColorsGUI implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (guiColorChanger.getSelectedItem() == guiColor[0]) {
            guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            settingsPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            gamePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            guiColorChanger.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            guiColorChangerLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                rb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                rb.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            difficultyLabel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            difficultyLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            difficultyPanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            currentScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            currentScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            currentScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            currentScorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            currentScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            highScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            highScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            highScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            highScorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            highScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
            highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        } else {
            guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            settingsPanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            scorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            guiColorChanger.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            guiColorChangerLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                rb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                rb.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            difficultyLabel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            difficultyLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            difficultyPanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
            guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            scorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            currentScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            currentScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            currentScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            currentScorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            currentScorePanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
            currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            highScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            highScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            highScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            highScorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
            highScorePanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
            highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MemoryGameView();
}
}
```

I really appreciate any help! (@camickr? :D)

Edit: I only need to do the files Model and View, no Controller needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. Define a a `Model` class that holds the information and logic the `View` needs. 
In this simple demo I implemented a model that has only one attribute the `View` needs namely `difficulty` :

```
class Model{

    private int difficulty = 0; //why not set a default value ? 

    Model(){
    }

    int getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    void setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
}
```

Now introduce a `View` class which is almost identical to `MemoryGameView` with one important difference: it has an instance of `Model` and uses it.
(Another difference is a design preference and not a must: unlike `MemoryGameView` it has a `JFrame` and it [does not extend one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867284/3992939).):

```
class View  {

    private JPanel gamePanel, settingsPanel, scorePanel;

    private final JButton[] button = new JButton[16];
    private JButton start;
    private JPanel buttonPanel, buttonPanel2;


    private JPanel difficultyPanel, difficultyPanel2;
    private JLabel difficultyLabel;
    private ButtonGroup difficultyButtonGroup;
    private final JRadioButton[] difficultyButton = new JRadioButton[4];

    private JComboBox guiColorChanger;
    private final String[] guiColor = new String[2];
    private JPanel guiColorChangerPanel;
    private JLabel guiColorChangerLabel;

    private JPanel currentScorePanel, currentScorePanel2, highScorePanel, highScorePanel2;
    private JLabel currentScoreLabel, currentScoreLabel2, highScoreLabel, highScoreLabel2;
    private int currentScore;
    private int highScore = 0;

    private int[] arrayAuto,arrayUser;
    private int counter;

    private Timer timer;

    private final Color babyBlue = new Color(137, 156, 240);
    private final Color brightRed = new Color(255, 69, 0);
    private final Color limeGreen = new Color(50, 205, 50);
    private final Color whiteBlue = new Color(240, 240, 255);
    private final Color blackBlue = new Color(0, 0, 15);

    private final Model model;

    public View(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Memory Game - by Marc");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        settingsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        scorePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        settingsPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        frame.add(settingsPanel);
        frame.add(gamePanel);
        frame.add(scorePanel);

        //GAME PANEL (CENTER) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //GAME GRID PANEL:

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 4, 4));
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            button[x] = new JButton();
            button[x].setBackground(babyBlue);
            button[x].setEnabled(false);
            button[x].addActionListener(new AttemptMemoryGame());
            button[x].setActionCommand(x + "");
            buttonPanel.add(button[x]);
        }

        buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(312, 312));
        buttonPanel2.add(buttonPanel);
        GridBagConstraints buttonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        buttonGBC.gridy = 0;
        buttonGBC.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        gamePanel.add(buttonPanel2, buttonGBC);

        //START BUTTON:

        start = new JButton("START");
        start.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
        GridBagConstraints startGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        startGBC.gridy = 1;
        startGBC.insets.top = 20;
        startGBC.insets.bottom = 20;
        gamePanel.add(start, startGBC);

        start.addActionListener(new CreateMemoryGame());
        timer = new Timer(750, new TimerListener());

        //SETTINGS PANEL (LEFT) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //GUI COLOR PANEL:

        guiColor[0] = "Light";
        guiColor[1] = "Dark";

        guiColorChangerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        settingsPanel.add(guiColorChangerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        guiColorChanger = new JComboBox(guiColor);
        guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        guiColorChanger.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        GridBagConstraints guiColorChangerGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        guiColorChangerGBC.gridy = 1;
        guiColorChangerGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 0, 50);
        guiColorChangerGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        guiColorChangerPanel.add(guiColorChanger, guiColorChangerGBC);

        guiColorChangerLabel = new JLabel("GUI Color Mode:");
        GridBagConstraints guiColorChangerLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        guiColorChangerLabelGBC.gridy = 0;
        guiColorChangerLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(30, 20, 5, 0);
        guiColorChangerLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        guiColorChangerPanel.add(guiColorChangerLabel, guiColorChangerLabelGBC);

        guiColorChanger.addActionListener(new ChangeColorsGUI());
        guiColorChanger.setFocusable(false);

        //GAME DIFFICULTY PANEL:

        difficultyPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        difficultyPanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        settingsPanel.add(difficultyPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        difficultyLabel = new JLabel("Difficulty:");
        GridBagConstraints difficultyLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        difficultyLabelGBC.gridy = 0;
        difficultyLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(30, 0, 5, 50);
        difficultyLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        difficultyPanel2.add(difficultyLabel, difficultyLabelGBC);

        difficultyPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        GridBagConstraints difficultyPanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        difficultyPanelGBC.gridy = 1;
        difficultyPanelGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 75, 100);
        difficultyPanel2.add(difficultyPanel, difficultyPanelGBC);

        GridBagConstraints difficultyGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        difficultyGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        difficultyGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        difficultyButton[0] = new JRadioButton("Easy [3]");
        difficultyButton[1] = new JRadioButton("Normal [5]");
        difficultyButton[2] = new JRadioButton("Hard [7]");
        difficultyButton[3] = new JRadioButton("Impossible [9]");

        difficultyButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            difficultyButton[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            difficultyButton[x].setActionCommand(x + "");
            difficultyGBC.gridy = x;
            difficultyPanel.add(difficultyButton[x], difficultyGBC);
            difficultyButtonGroup.add(difficultyButton[x]);
            difficultyButton[x].addActionListener(new SelectDifficulty());
        }

        //SCORE PANEL (RIGHT) --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //CURRENT SCORE:

        currentScorePanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        currentScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        scorePanel.add(currentScorePanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        currentScoreLabel2 = new JLabel("Score:        ");
        GridBagConstraints currentScoreLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        currentScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 0;
        currentScoreLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        currentScoreLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        currentScorePanel2.add(currentScoreLabel2, currentScoreLabelGBC);

        currentScorePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        currentScorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        GridBagConstraints currentScorePanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        currentScorePanelGBC.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 100, 100);
        currentScorePanelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        currentScorePanel2.add(currentScorePanel, currentScorePanelGBC);

        currentScoreLabel = new JLabel("        ");
        currentScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 1;
        currentScorePanel.add(currentScoreLabel, currentScoreLabelGBC);


        //HIGHSCORE:

        highScorePanel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        highScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
        scorePanel.add(highScorePanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        highScoreLabel2 = new JLabel("Highscore: ");
        GridBagConstraints highScoreLabelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        highScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 0;
        highScoreLabelGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        highScoreLabelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        highScorePanel2.add(highScoreLabel2, highScoreLabelGBC);

        highScorePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        highScorePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        GridBagConstraints highScorePanelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        highScorePanelGBC.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 100, 100);
        highScorePanelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        highScorePanel2.add(highScorePanel, highScorePanelGBC);

        highScoreLabel = new JLabel("        ");
        highScoreLabelGBC.gridx = 1;
        highScorePanel.add(highScoreLabel, highScoreLabelGBC);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class CreateMemoryGame implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (model.getDifficulty() != 0) {
                counter = 0;
                for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                    rb.setEnabled(false);
                }
                for (JButton b: button) {
                    b.setBackground(babyBlue);
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                }
                start.setEnabled(false);
                arrayAuto = new int[model.getDifficulty()];
                arrayAuto[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
                for (int x = 1; x < model.getDifficulty(); x++) {
                    arrayAuto[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
                    while (arrayAuto[x] == arrayAuto[x - 1]) {
                        arrayAuto[x] = (int)(Math.random() * 16);
                    }
                }
                arrayUser = Arrays.copyOf(arrayAuto, arrayAuto.length);
                button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(limeGreen);
                timer.start();
            } else {
                Object[] options = {"OK"};
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please select a Difficulty.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        options,
                        options[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(babyBlue);
            arrayAuto = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayAuto, 1, arrayAuto.length);
            if (arrayAuto.length == 0) {
                timer.stop();
                for (JButton b: button) {
                    b.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                button[arrayAuto[0]].setBackground(limeGreen);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AttemptMemoryGame implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand()) == arrayUser[counter]) {
                if (counter != 0) {
                    button[arrayUser[counter - 1]].setBackground(babyBlue);
                }
                button[arrayUser[counter]].setBackground(limeGreen);
                counter++;
                currentScore += model.getDifficulty();
                currentScoreLabel.setText("  " + currentScore + "  ");
            } else {
                if (currentScore > highScore) {
                    highScore = currentScore;
                    highScoreLabel.setText("  " + highScore + "  ");
                }
                currentScore = 0;
                currentScoreLabel.setText("        ");
                for (int x = 0; x < model.getDifficulty(); x++) {
                    button[arrayUser[x]].setBackground(brightRed);
                }
                start.setEnabled(true);
                for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                    rb.setEnabled(true);
                }
                for (JButton b: button) {
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            if (counter == arrayUser.length) {
                start.setEnabled(true);
                for (int x = 0; x < counter - 1; x++) {
                    button[arrayUser[x]].setBackground(limeGreen);
                }
                for (JButton b: button) {
                    b.setEnabled(false);
                }
                for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                    rb.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SelectDifficulty implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(0 + "")) {
                model.setDifficulty(3);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(2 + "")) {
                model.setDifficulty(7);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(3 + "")) {
                model.setDifficulty(9);
            } else {
                model.setDifficulty(5);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChangeColorsGUI implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (guiColorChanger.getSelectedItem() == guiColor[0]) {
                guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                settingsPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                gamePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                guiColorChanger.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                guiColorChangerLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                    rb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    rb.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                difficultyLabel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                difficultyLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                difficultyPanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                scorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                currentScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                currentScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                currentScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                currentScorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                currentScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                highScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                highScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                highScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                highScorePanel.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                highScorePanel2.setBackground(whiteBlue);
                highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            } else {
                guiColorChanger.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                settingsPanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                scorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                guiColorChangerPanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                buttonPanel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                guiColorChanger.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                guiColorChangerLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                difficultyPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                for (JRadioButton rb: difficultyButton) {
                    rb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    rb.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                difficultyLabel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                difficultyLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                difficultyPanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
                guiColorChanger.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                difficultyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                scorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                currentScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                currentScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                currentScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                currentScorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                currentScorePanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
                currentScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                highScoreLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                highScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                highScoreLabel2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                highScorePanel.setBackground(blackBlue);
                highScorePanel2.setBackground(blackBlue);
                highScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MemoryGameView` becomes the controller, and it is as simple as:

```
public class MemoryGameView{

    public MemoryGameView() {
        Model model = new  Model();
        View view = new View(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MemoryGameView();
    }
}
```

Follow this [link](https://repl.it/repls/LowestUsefulTelevision) for a complete working prototype.
To continue: refactor more attributes (data and logic) from `View` to `Model`.
You may need to add listener so `View` can listen to changes in `Model`.

Side note: if indeed *no Controller needed* you can simply eliminate `MemoryGameView` and refactor its functionality to a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = new  Model();
    View view = new View(model);
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The following members might go into the model class:

- difficulty
- currentScore
- highScore
- arrayAuto
- arrayUser
- counter

Effectively the "pure" information.

The view should contain only ui code, i.e. Swing-Code. Since the game loop (timer) might be regarded as business code it would probably be a good idea to move it to the controller.

I did a quick google about swing and mvc: You might try to use existing frameworks like [this](https://github.com/kasperisager/swing-mvc) for mvc.