# Why I can't see the title of JFrame in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm making a group project which is Java console GUI. This is my code for the Java console GUI:

Here's the output from my code.
[image]

Why I can't see the title for this output? I already input my title tho. Can somebody fix my layout?

Here's the coding part.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Homepage5FeatureKeysGUIConsole extends JFrame {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        Homepage5FeatureKeysGUIConsole homePage = new Homepage5FeatureKeysGUIConsole();
        homePage.createAndShowGUI();
});
}

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        setTitle("Select Feature");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1, 10, 10));

        JButton buttonFeature1 = createFeatureButton("Admin Registration");
        panel.add(buttonFeature1);

        JButton buttonFeature2 = createFeatureButton("Volunteer Registration");
        panel.add(buttonFeature2);

        JButton buttonFeature3 = createFeatureButton("Disaster Report");
        panel.add(buttonFeature3);

        JButton buttonFeature4 = createFeatureButton("Safe Shelter");
        panel.add(buttonFeature4);

        JButton buttonFeature5 = createFeatureButton("Fund Raising");
        panel.add(buttonFeature5);

        JButton buttonEmergencyContact = createFeatureButton("Emergency Contact");
        panel.add(buttonEmergencyContact);

        setContentPane(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
}

    private JButton createFeatureButton(String label) {
        JButton button = new JButton(label);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setBackground(new Color(124, 200, 255));
        button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> handleFeatureButton(label));
        return button;
}

    private void handleFeatureButton(String feature) {
        switch (feature) {
            case "Admin Registration" -> openAdminAppGUI();
            case "Volunteer Registration" -> openVolunteerAppGUI();
            case "Disaster Report" -> openDisasterReportGUI();
            case "Safe Shelter" -> openSafeShelterGUI();
            case "Fund Raising" -> openFundRaisingGUI();
            case "Emergency Contact" -> openEmergencyContactGUI();
}
}

    private void openAdminAppGUI() {
        AdminAppGUI adminAppGUI = new AdminAppGUI();
        adminAppGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}

    private void openVolunteerAppGUI() {
        VolunteerAppGUI volunteerAppGUI = new VolunteerAppGUI();
        volunteerAppGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}

    private void openDisasterReportGUI() {
        DisasterReportGUI disasterReportGUI = new DisasterReportGUI();
        disasterReportGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}

    private void openSafeShelterGUI() {
        SafeShelterGUI safeShelterGUI = new SafeShelterGUI();
        safeShelterGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}

    private void openFundRaisingGUI() {
        FundRaisingGUIConsole fundRaisingGUI = new FundRaisingGUIConsole();
        fundRaisingGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}

    private void openEmergencyContactGUI() {
        EmergencyContactGUI emergencyContactGUI = new EmergencyContactGUI();
        emergencyContactGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        dispose();
}
}
```

I've been trying to fix the layout but it still didn't work at all and I can't see the title from the output which is "Select Feature".

Comment: Likely because the window is so narrow there's no room to show the title.

Comment: You might not want to extend from `JFrame`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867148/why-do-we-need-to-extend-jframe-in-a-swing-application

Comment: have you tried to maximize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add manually the dimensions:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
```

Comment: (1-) Don't use setPreferredSize() to manually control the size of components. It is the job of every Swing component to determine its own preferred size.

Comment: I guess with frame.pack() the frame resizes to match it's child components but not the window title. Hence setting the preferred size would be required in this case. Or addition of components.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setPreferredSize() to control the size of components. It is the job of every Swing component to determine its own preferred size.

If you want extra space on the panel you could always add an `EmptyBorder` to the panel.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

Or, if you really want the buttons to be larger then you can use:

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(...) );
```

to add extra space to the button.